# Should I skip tests with maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, unit-testing, testing, build

## tl;dr

Should I skip tests in maven?

## Long version

(I don't know, whether this matters.)

I use Java EE eclipse, I have tests and the code in the proper maven directory.

Why should I (not) skip the tests during build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Never make the test skipping as a normal thing of your build.
Doing it regularly is a vicious circle that will make your tests useless and your application less robust.

## Long version

**Automatically build from the IDE (Eclipse or any other)**

IDEs that allow to use Maven as a build tool don't execute unit tests at each build as by default they don't execute the `test` goal, neither the `package` goal.  Instead of they focus on the compiler plugin (`compile` and `test-compile`) as well the resources plugin (`resources` and `test-resources`).
So unit tests should not be executed at each automatically build performed by your IDE.

**Build with mvn package/install**

> Why should I (not) skip the tests during build?

Your question refers Maven but it could be any other build tool or any programming language and it would have the same kind of consequences.

First, ask you the question why do we write unit tests.
We write them **to validate the behavior of our components** and also **to be warned as the  behavior of our components don't behave any longer as expected (regression detecting)**.

Ignoring regularly the tests execution means that you will take the risk that your covered by unit tests components having regressions in their behavior without that you are aware about them.
And later other regressions may occur and you will still be unaware of them.
And much later many of your tests will fail as you never corrected them to stay conform to the expected behavior.

As a test failure prevents the build, it will very probably result to make you skip/disable/comment/delete unit tests because these fail too often and for too many cases.
Your unit tests will become dust and you will lose all benefits provided by unit tests.

**But so why does the skip tests option exist ?**

I recommend/use them only for **corner cases** such as the followings (not exhaustive) and **only temporarily** :

- legacy projects which many tests were not maintained.
  As correcting them will take too much time, in a first time, you don't have other choices that skipping them to build your component.
  And as soon as possible you have to disable unreliable tests (`@Ignore` with JUnit), correct these that may be or plan them. In this way you could re-enable the tests execution and let working tests to be regularly executed.
- projects where the tests may fail according to the execution environment. 
  Here again it should be a temporary workaround and isolated too.
  Indeed, as soon as possible you have to find a way to make the tests successful whatever the environment  where they are executed.